How can I use transition in CSS handling state with React?
  const MyCart = () => {
            const { cart, myCartVisible, setMyCartVisible, dispatch } = useCart();
            const [ subtotal, setSubTotal ] = useState(0);
        
            useEffect(() => {
                if (myCartVisible) {
                    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                } else {
                    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
                }
            }, [ cart, myCartVisible ]);
        
        
            const toggleCartVisibility = () => {
                if (!myCartVisible) {
                    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // Bloquea el scroll del body al abrir el carrito
                } else {
                    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'; // Restaura el scroll del body al cerrar el carrito
                }
                setMyCartVisible(!myCartVisible);
            };
            return(
            <div className='cart-container' id='cart-container'>
               <div className={`${myCartVisible ? 'overlay' : 
                ''}`} onClick={toggleCartVisibility}></div>
               <div className={`my-cart ${myCartVisible ? 'cart- 
                active' : ''}`} id='my-cart'>
               </div>
             </div>
       );
    }

I have a component of this style, that when x button is pressed in the header component, the myCartVisible is changed. So if is true it proceeds to re-render showing the content of the shopping cart (I did not include the content because it seems unnecessary to me, the functionality works well). I added the CSS from the first question which is this:
.my-cart {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 25;
  padding: 24px 32px;
  width: 20%;
  transition: transform 0.9s ease; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.cart-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

The problem is that the entry and exit transition are not made, it is very robust and ugly and I have no idea how to animate it, it seems that the transition all 0.9s is ignored;. Maybe someone could help me. If the question is incorrectly formulated or you need more information, please let me know.
I tried CSSTransitions but didn't worked.

The transitions are not being ignored (try setting them to something larger to see). What is happening is that your cart is so far to the right with that right: -100% that it's taking time to get to right: 0 less the width of itself, so you don't see most of the transition and the last bit is very quick. There's no need for the the right: -100%.

Could you please add code sandbox or fiddle link for quick debug?

It seems that your issue is in CSS itself and doesn't have to do with your React Component. More specifically there is a conflict between CSS property right and transform since it will not produce the animation that you wish for if you use both properties.
So make sure that right property is always 0 and you are using your animation with transform and transition. Your final CSS will look like this:
.my-cart {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 25;
  padding: 24px 32px;
  width: 20%;
  transition: transform 0.9s ease; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.cart-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}


It doesn't work, see, the cart is still showing bad, but if is active and I make a change like the background color, the change is made with the transition. I will add some more code about the componente itself if there is a problem with that.
